# GL_INVALID_OPERATION caused by samplerCube

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently learning WebGL, and expanding my code with something new every time. However, this error keeps throwing:

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext-0111BCC8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glFramebufferTexture2D: <- error from previous GL command
```

In my javascript code, I set a `uniform bool`, whether the object I'm rendering has reflection or not (earlier in my render-code I've created a cubemap and rendered the reflection to it). When it has reflection, I also set the active texture unit, bind the cubemap texture and set the `uniform textureCube uReflectionMap`, like below:

```
if (obj.reflects && obj.reflectionMap != null) {
    this.gl.activeTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE10);
    this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, obj.reflectionMap.glTexture);
    this.gl.uniform1i(p.uniforms["uReflectionMap"], 10);
    this.gl.uniform1i(p.uniforms["uReflects"], true);
} else {
    this.gl.uniform1i(p.uniforms["uReflects"], false);
}
```

**I'm using texture unit 10 only for this part of the code (only for the reflection cubemaps)**

The fragment-shader code:

```
if(uReflects){
    vec3 lookup = reflect(eyeDirection, normal);
    color += textureCube(uReflectionMap, -lookup); //no errors when this line is commented
}
```

When I comment the 'highlighted' line above, everything works fine (except that there is no reflection obviously). Thus, I expected the `if(uReflects)` to be wrong (so that this piece of code exectutes even when there is no uReflectionMap set. Simply changed the commented line to `color += vec4(1.)`, and only the objects which I've set to reflect were completely white.

What I tried thereafter, which fixed the problem, is setting the `uReflectionMap` to texture unit 10 (`this.gl.uniform1i(p.uniforms["uReflectionMap"], 10);` in the else statement), regardless of whether my object has a reflectionMap.

This to me seems weird, because the textureCube function isn't executed when uReflects is false, but still generates errors when uReflectionMap is not set.

I hope the question is understandable, I have a lot of code and have no idea what I should add to the question (because perhaps something else is interfering, which I've overseen).

I've done all this testing in Google Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m. Just ran it in IE, and it seems to give a more elaborated error message, though it's such poorly written Dutch that I have no idea how to interpret it, not to mention translate. <strike>Will try firefox now.</strike>Firefox doesn't give any warnings, but it doesn't work either...

---

**Response @gman:**

This is the code where I create the cubemap texture ():

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);


var size = 1024;

this.reflectionFrameBuffers = [];
this.reflectionRenderBuffers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    this.reflectionRenderBuffers[i] = gl.createRenderbuffer();
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.reflectionRenderBuffers[i]);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, size, size);


    this.reflectionFrameBuffers[i] = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.reflectionFrameBuffers[i]);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, texture, 0);
    gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.reflectionRenderBuffers[i]);

    gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);//this throws no errors
}

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
```

This piece clears all the sides before rendering:

```
this.gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
this.gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
this.gl.cullFace(this.gl.BACK);

for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, obj.reflectionFrameBuffers[j]);
    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

This is the code for rendering to the cubemap (it is surrounded by other for-loops and code to feed the reflectionMapper shader):

```
for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, obj.reflectionFrameBuffers[k]);
    this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(p.uniforms["uViewMatrix"], false, obj.reflectionViewMatrices[k].array);//these view matrices determine which direction to look in
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.facesArray.length / 9);
}
```

Comment: According to the error message it has nothing to with your shader. `GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glFramebufferTexture2D` it would be good to show us code where you call glFramebufferTexture2D. Are you maybe trying to assign your cube texture as an attachment but not setting the correct target?

Comment: @gman thanks for the response. I was wondering that as well, the error seems unrelated to the textureCube line, even though commenting it fixes the issue. I've added all the relevant code of creating the cubemap and rendering it. I use almost exactly the same code for pointlight shadow mapping, which works perfectly. I've gone over all the lines of code to make sure I've not skipped anything important.
I've also updated my "further testing" section, which basically rejects my first thought.
I've currently made the render skip over every object that doesn't have a reflection cubemap. No errors.

Comment: I decided to check out IE again, and instead of throwing the warning a lot of times, it only throws an error twice, on the drawArrays call. After that it renders fine. I tried to translate it the best I could: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: variables of different exampletypes (sampler types, like sampler2D and samplerCube?) within a programobject (program with vert & frag shader?) can't refer to the same patternimageunit (texture unit?)

Comment: @gman I edited the @ into the previous comment, that's probably the reason why you weren't notfied of my comment. Sorry to bump this.

Comment: @MarjinS95, well the new error message suggests you didn't set your sampler uniforms correctly. For example if you have both a sampler2D and a samplerCubemap in your shader and you don't set their corresponding uniforms to different texture units you'll get this error, including if you don't set the uniforms at all since they default to 0.

Comment: @gman I was thinking something along those lines as well, but I've checked and I only use TEXTURE10 for specifically that reflection cubemap. None of the other sampler uniforms are set to 10. As you can see in the further testing section, I use one texture unit for the sampler2D, and another for the samplerCube, to no avail. I've checked and every bindTexture call in my render pass has an activeTexture and correct uniform call prior to it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your boolean, `uIsCube` is true or false. Regardless that shader will access both samplers. So your conditional setup code is wrong. You need to always set up both cubemap textures and 2d textures and they need to be on different texture units. [I made a small sample here](http://codepen.io/greggman/pen/WvVEBR). I get the same errors when I don't correct setup the sampler's texture units. [If I set them the errors go away](http://codepen.io/greggman/pen/yNmomP)

Comment: @gman the code you showed doesn't show the conditional if I have within my shader. I've used it many times with sampler2D with issues, altered your sample [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVKQGO) to display this. Same goes for samplerCube, there are no errors when not setting the samplerCube and then ignoring it with the if inside the shader. [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpOQLG). I am just wondering why the same doesn't work in my code (and that is, without the 'extra testing' code. I don't use either a samplerCube or texture2D).

Comment: That sample you posted is not ignoring it. you commented out access to samplerCube. Comment it back in (with the conditional) and the error returns. Shaders don't work like normal code. All paths are executed always. If you don't actually use the uniform (like in the sample you pasted) then it *might* be optimized out but in the case of selecting one or the other by a uniform bool it has to make the shader that accesses both. See http://codepen.io/greggman/pen/qdeoor

Comment: @gman that commented line should have been completely gone. I am only using the samplerCube **inbetween** the if. As seen in the second example, there is **no error** when `useTexture` is false **and** `u_tex1` is not set. [This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNqMrp) is an example of the code I am currently using, which doesn't throw an error in the example, but does in my own code. So, as you say it always executes all code paths, I don't know how to explan why it works in the codepen example, and not in my own code. If it's optimised out we should check getTranslatedShaderSource of the example.

Comment: ... I've checked my own code, and it's not optimised out when I check getTranslatedShaderSource (long time ago I just put `false` inside the if and wondered why there were no errors anymore. When I found out about this function I saw it was optimised out). I'm wondering how to call this function for your library to check. Since, because it's a uniform, at compile time you don't yet know if you can leave it out or not.

Comment: That function doesn't really tell you if it was optimized out. It tells you what the browser sent to the graphics driver. The graphics driver might itself also optimize things out. The only way to know if  a uniform was optimized out is to check if the uniform location exists.

Comment: @gman thanks for that. I've checked my `uReflects` and `uReflectionMap`, and they both exist. Rereading your previous comment: So it's completely normal that a function throws an error even when it's not executed because of an encapsulating if? I'm still completely dazzled by the fact that it doesn't throw an error in the example, and that my own code has a lot of the same if-structures, but with sampler2D's, which do not throw any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have 2 uniform samplers of different types pointing to the same texture unit.

Shaders generally execute all paths. What I mean is if you have this in your shader

```
if (someCondition) {
  a = value1;
} else {
  a = value2;
}
```

What really happens in the shader is something like

```
a = value1 * (someCondition ? 1 : 0) + value2 * (someCondition ? 0 : 1);
```

or better yet

```
// mix will be 1.0 if someCondition is true, else 0.0
float mix = step(0.5, 1.0 - float(someCondition)); 

a = value1 * mix + value2 * (1 - mix);
```

Now there are no branches. GPUs don't branch, that's how they get their speed. Note I made that example up but it shows the point that both value1 and value2 are used regardless of the condition. That assumes the condition is variable. In your example

```
uniform bool uIsCube;
uniform sampler2D uTwoD;
uniform samplerCube uCube;

varying vec3 vTexCoord;

void main(void){
    if(uIsCube){
        gl_FragColor = textureCube(uCube, vTexCoord);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTwoD, vTexCoord.st);
    }
}
```

`uIsCube` is variable. I can't be known at compile time, only runtime, so both `uCube` and `uTwoD` are used always and need to be set to different texture units using `gl.uniform1i`

If on the other hand if the condition was a constant like this

```
#define IsCube false

void main(void){
    if(IsCube){
        gl_FragColor = textureCube(uCube, vTexCoord);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTwoD, vTexCoord.st);
    }
}
```

Then at compile time the compiler would *possibly* remove one of the samplers. I say *possibly* because IIRC the spec doesn't require a driver to optimize away unused code in the shader.

Also note that uniforms all default to 0 so if you don't set the uniforms then both samplers will be pointing to texture unit .

You can check if a uniform was optimized away by checking for its location

```
var uCubeLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uCube");
if (!uCubeLoc) {
  // uCubeLoc does not exist or was optimized out
}
```

To see if there's an error in your code related to multiple samplers of different types pointing to the same texture unit you could a call to a function like this just before each `gl.draw___` call.

```
function checkForConflictingSamplers() {
  var prg = gl.getParameter(gl.CURRENT_PROGRAM);
  var units = {};
  var numUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter(prg, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);

  function checkUniform(name, type) {
    var unit = gl.getUniform(prg, gl.getUniformLocation(prg, name));
    var unitInfo = units[unit];
    if (unitInfo === undefined) {
      units[unit] = { 
        type: type,
        name: name,
      };
    } else if (unitInfo.type !== type) {
      console.error("unit " + unit + " is being used by conflicting samplers " + name + " and " + unitInfo.name);
    }
  }    

  for (var ii = 0; ii < numUniforms; ++ii) {
    var uniformInfo = gl.getActiveUniform(prg, ii);
    if (!uniformInfo) {
      continue;
    }
    var name = uniformInfo.name;
    var type = uniformInfo.type;
    var isArray = (uniformInfo.size > 1 && name.substr(-3) === "[0]");
    // remove the array suffix.
    if (name.substr(-3) === "[0]") {
      name = name.substr(0, name.length - 3);
    }

    if (type === gl.SAMPLER_2D || type === gl.SAMPLER_CUBE) {
      if (isArray) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < uniformInfo.size; ++ii) {
          checkUniform(name + "[" + ii + "]", type);
        }
      } else {
        checkUniform(name, type);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently not using two samplers, just either samplerCube or nothing, but your example of `a = value1 * (someCondition ? 1 : 0) + value2 * (someCondition ? 0 : 1);` makes me understand why the code errors. However, I'm still wondering why there are no errors in [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNqMrp) case, which would compile similar to `textureCube(u_tex1, vec3) * (useTexture ? 1 : 0)`, and should error since `u_tex1` is not defined.

Comment: There's no errors in that case because there's only one sampler. You can't have a conflict between 2 samplers if there's only one. `u_tex1` is defined. If you mean it's not setup there's no error because all uniforms default to 0 and all texture units have a default black texture setup.

Comment: Now I'm completely dazzled. Code similar to the example is what throws the error, and you seem to have responded to some unrelated code I've added in my question (which I've currently removed for clarity).

Comment: thanks for your edit! This made the coin drop: **because all uniforms default to 0**. When I don't set uReflectionMap in my own code it defaults to texture unit 0 which contains a sampler2D!